# C program to put the output into a new file

Tags: c, file, pointers

So i have een solving a problem where i have to find the prime numbers from the input file and save those prime numbers in an output file called output.txt.But If there are no prime numbers in the input file, i'll have to write “No prime numbers found” in the output file.So when i completed the code when there is no prime number it shows No prime numbers found 5-6 times and i only want it to appear 1 time.What is my mistake here?I am totally a noob here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Primecheck(const int number);

int main()
{
    FILE* Number, 
        * Prime_N;

    int num;
    char sentence[50] = "No prime numbers found";
    int length = strlen(sentence);
    int i;

    Number = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    Prime_N = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (Number == NULL || Prime_N == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("File opened and Reading Done \n\n");

    while (fscanf(Number, "%d", &num) != -1)
    {
        if (Primecheck(num) == 1)
            fprintf(Prime_N, "%d\n", num);
        else
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                fputc(sentence[i], Prime_N);
            }
    }

    fclose(Number);
    fclose(Prime_N);

    printf("Overwrite Success.");

    return 0;
}

int Primecheck(const int number)
{
    int i;

    if (number < 0)
        return 0;

    for (i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++)
    {

        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Go over your logic. That will make clear where you are wrong. Or use a debugger to step through the program.

Comment: What happens if you read a number and it is not prime?

Comment: Instead of writing that message within the loop, set a flag when you output a result. And then *after* the loop, check the flag to see if there were any results, and output the message before `fclose`.

Comment: Define `sentence` as `char sentence[] = "No prime numbers found";`. Then `length` will be `sizeof sentence - 1`. And store it with `fprintf` instead of loop and `fputc`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
else
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        fputc(sentence[i] ,Prime_N);
    }
```

you can just write

```
else
    printf("No prime numbers found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , as I see from your code , each time you read a number from the file you check if prime write it or write  `sentence` . so of course you get multiple output ,
you should write the number to `char*` then check if changed after reading from `Number` and checking if prime write the number in the `char*` after the loop just check if the length of the `char*` that you stored the primes in it if changed write it else write your sentence ... Done

something like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


typedef struct {
    char* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} string;

void init_string(string* s, size_t size){
    s->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    s->capacity = size;
    s->size = 0;
}

void append(string* s,const char* str){
    if(s->capacity - s->size < strlen(str)){
        s->data = (char*)realloc(s->data, sizeof(char)* 4 * strlen(str));
    }strcat(s->data, str);
}

void free_string(string* s){
    free(s->data);
}


int is_odd(int n){
    return n%2;
}

int main(){
    int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};

    string str;
    init_string(&str,1);
    char* snum;
    for(int i=0; i<18; i++){
        if(!is_odd(i)){
            sprintf(snum,"%d",num[i]);
            append(&str, snum);
            append(&str, "\n");
        }
        //printf(snum);
        //strcat(str, snum);
    }
    printf("%s",str.data);    
    free_string(&str);
    //printf(str);
    return 0;
}
```